# Hadith in Omer Suleiman Talk

Tags: hadith, source-identification

[In this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=91WY8pN1a-c) (around 30:00 or so) Omer Suleiman talks about a hadith (possibly paraphrasing) that in the Day of Judgment, and for certain people, Allah will show them their sins and turn them into good deeds, and the person will be so surprised that he will look for sins that the angel might have skipped.

Can someone point me to the source of this hadith or narration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hadith you are asking about is most likely the one narrated by Abu Dharr, and documented in Sahih Muslim Hadith 375, Jami' at-Tirmidhi Hadith 2596, and in Musnad Ahmad  Hadith 20517, among other books:

> حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ نُمَيْرٍ، حَدَّثَنَا أَبِي، حَدَّثَنَا الأَعْمَشُ، عَنِ الْمَعْرُورِ بْنِ سُوَيْدٍ، عَنْ أَبِي ذَرٍّ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ إِنِّي لأَعْلَمُ آخِرَ أَهْلِ الْجَنَّةِ دُخُولاً الْجَنَّةَ وَآخِرَ أَهْلِ النَّارِ خُرُوجًا مِنْهَا رَجُلٌ يُؤْتَى بِهِ يَوْمَ الْقِيَامَةِ فَيُقَالُ اعْرِضُوا عَلَيْهِ صِغَارَ ذُنُوبِهِ وَارْفَعُوا عَنْهُ كِبَارَهَا ‏.‏ فَتُعْرَضُ عَلَيْهِ صِغَارُ ذُنُوبِهِ فَيُقَالُ عَمِلْتَ يَوْمَ كَذَا وَكَذَا كَذَا وَكَذَا وَعَمِلْتَ يَوْمَ كَذَا وَكَذَا كَذَا وَكَذَا ‏.‏ فَيَقُولُ نَعَمْ ‏.‏ لاَ يَسْتَطِيعُ أَنْ يُنْكِرَ وَهُوَ مُشْفِقٌ مِنْ كِبَارِ ذُنُوبِهِ أَنْ تُعْرَضَ عَلَيْهِ ‏.‏ فَيُقَالُ لَهُ فَإِنَّ لَكَ مَكَانَ كُلِّ سَيِّئَةٍ حَسَنَةً ‏.‏ فَيَقُولُ رَبِّ قَدْ عَمِلْتُ أَشْيَاءَ لاَ أَرَاهَا هَا هُنَا ‏"‏ ‏.‏ فَلَقَدْ رَأَيْتُ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ضَحِكَ حَتَّى بَدَتْ نَوَاجِذُهُ ‏.‏
>
> Abu Dharr reported that Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said: I know the last of the inhabitants of Paradise to enter it and the last of the inhabitants of Hell to come out of it. He is a man who would be brought on the Day of Resurrection and it will be said: Present his minor sins to him, and withhold from him his serious sins. Then the minor sins would be placed before him, and it would be said: On such and such a day you did so and so and on such and such a day you did so and so. He would say: Yes. It will not be possible for him to deny, while he would be afraid lest serious sins should be presented before him. It would be said to him: In place of every evil deed you will have a good deed. He will say: My Lord! I have done things I do not see here. I indeed saw the Messenger of Allah laugh till his front teeth were exposed.
>
> <sub>— [Sahih Muslim, Book 1, Hadith 375](https://sunnah.com/muslim:190a)</sub>